# Request from Smart Home Skill to cloud server

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a Smart Home Skill by following this tutorial

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/steps-to-build-a-smart-home-skill.html

What I am not able to figure out is that how can I get email of user and discover devices owned by a user?

The above article doesn't have any information regarding how there will be communication between the Skill or lambda function and the cloud server.